# NullpointerException when trying to connect Application to AxonIQ Console

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, axon

I'm trying to connect my axon application to https://console.axoniq.io/
I do not use Spring because I have a quarkus-application. So in my pom.xml I have the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.axoniq.console</groupId>
        <artifactId>console-framework-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my Axon-Configuration class I pasted the code what I found in the instruction of my axoniq-space:

```
        Configurer configurer = DefaultConfigurer.defaultConfiguration() //
            .configureAggregate(MyAggregate.class)
            .configureSerializer(config -> commmandSerializerForAxonServer());
    AxoniqConsoleConfigurerModule
            .builder(
                    "95d0cfd4-0",
                    "f3094e246fd84ae6a9e4cde5d12fe2f7",
                    "MyAxonProject"
            )
            .build()
            .configureModule(configurer);

    Configuration configuration = configurer.start();
```

But when I run my application as soon as the configuration is loaded I get the following Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method io.axoniq.console.framework.eventprocessor.EventProcessorManager.<init>, parameter transactionManager
at io.axoniq.console.framework.eventprocessor.EventProcessorManager.<init>(EventProcessorManager.kt)
at io.axoniq.console.framework.AxoniqConsoleConfigurerModule.lambda$configureModule$3(AxoniqConsoleConfigurerModule.java:135)
at org.axonframework.config.Component.get(Component.java:85)
at org.axonframework.config.DefaultConfigurer$ConfigurationImpl.getComponent(DefaultConfigurer.java:1134)
at org.axonframework.config.Configuration.getComponent(Configuration.java:278)
at io.axoniq.console.framework.AxoniqConsoleConfigurerModule.lambda$configureModule$6(AxoniqConsoleConfigurerModule.java:146)
at org.axonframework.config.Component.get(Component.java:85)
at org.axonframework.config.DefaultConfigurer$ConfigurationImpl.getComponent(DefaultConfigurer.java:1134)
at org.axonframework.config.Configuration.getComponent(Configuration.java:278)
at io.axoniq.console.framework.AxoniqConsoleConfigurerModule.lambda$configureModule$14(AxoniqConsoleConfigurerModule.java:209)
at org.axonframework.config.DefaultConfigurer.lambda$invokeInitHandlers$57(DefaultConfigurer.java:994)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
at org.axonframework.config.DefaultConfigurer.invokeInitHandlers(DefaultConfigurer.java:994)
at org.axonframework.config.DefaultConfigurer.buildConfiguration(DefaultConfigurer.java:955)
at org.axonframework.config.Configurer.start(Configurer.java:618)
at at.axon.configuration.AxonConfigurer.configure(AxonConfigurer.java:32)
```

The application do also not appear in Axoniq-Console as well. I didn't find any example on the internet. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for marking this, @Veilchen4ever.
You have actually uncovered a minor bug here.

Throughout Axon Framework, if a component isn't present, a sensible default is set. The `console-framework-client` was simply lacking that default logic.
There's a [PR out](https://github.com/AxonIQ/console-framework-client/pull/56), which is already approved, to set this default.

Even better, it is already released, under version [1.4.1](https://github.com/AxonIQ/console-framework-client/releases/tag/V1.4.1).

Comment: Thanks a lot. With 1.4.1 it works as expected